# RecyclerView faz imageview desaparecer

Tags: android, imageview, android-recyclerview

Simples. O Recycler View faz o imageView desaparecer após eu rolar para o fim da lista e voltar para o topo. Por exemplo, no caso, a primeira imagem simplesmente some.

Era assim: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aEMFG.png
Após ir até o final da lista e voltar, ficou assim:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/IOqaz.png

Não estou usando nenhuma biblioteca. A imageview daí é normal, sem qualquer alteração. Inclusive essa foto é um background que coloquei no XML.

Os textos não se alteram, dá pra perceber.

Comment: Amigo, sempre que abrir uma pergunta, coloque o código total ou parcial que permita a quem lhe quer ajudar saber o que realmente está acontecendo. Seu código poderia ter vários detalhes que não conseguimos ver. O Leonardo deu um ótimo "chute" baseado nos efeitos, mas sem saber a causa!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

É bom você colocar o código junto da pergunta, pra ajudar na solução.

Mas esse "problema" já é conhecido em RecyclerView.

Você tem um adapter que cria a sua lista, certo?

Provavelmente na hora de você setar a imagem, você está usando um IF, certo?

Sempre que você for trabalhar com RecyclerView+Adapter você obrigatóriamente deve pensar no ELSE também, porque como o nome diz, ele recicla as celulas para criar o restante da lista.

Por exemplo:

```
if(url.imgview != null){
    image.setImageURI(Uri.parse(url.imgview));             
} else {
    image.setImageDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher));   
}
```

Se a URL estiver vazia ou nula, automáticamente vai ser colocado o icone da aplicação, evitando assim que imagens já colocadas se repitam.

Comment: Isso não é um problema com a RecyclerView, isso é um problema com a programação errada! Agora, acho que deram -1 na sua sua resposta porque na abertura dela você fez um comentário que deveria ter sido adicionado como comentário à pergunta em si!

Comment: @Loudenvier Por isso mesmo eu coloquei que provavelmente ele está fazendo dessa forma, e coloquei um exemplo, pois ele não colocou o código do problema dele, a guerra por reputação aqui é maior que a vontade de ajudar alguém, ja acostumei

Comment: Valeu pela resposta, mas não era a certa. Eu cometi um erro que me custou muitas e muitas horas. Já solucionei o que era. Eu estava pegando a posição no onBindViewHolder pelo holder.getAdapterPosition, sendo que eu deveria usar a position somente.
O engraçado é que eu já fiz muito recycler view, e dessa fez não sei porque eu errei. Estava ficando louco.
Vou positivar mas não vou dar como certa. Valeu

Comment: Leonardo, ainda bem que quer ajudar. Uma resposta só ajuda alguém se resolver o problema colocado. Responder a perguntas que não disponibilizam toda a informação, que obrigam a resposta começar por *"É bom você colocar o código junto da pergunta, pra ajudar na solução"* e no meio ter *"Você tem um adapter que cria a sua lista, certo?"*, são "chute". O que se pretende aqui são respostas de qualidade, que respondam ao problema. Só assim elas poderão ajudar alguém.

Comment: *"Guerra de reputação"*?, não sei a que se refere. As respostas recebem voto negativo quando não têm qualidade além que quem vota vê a sua reputação diminuída.

Comment: Tinha outro problema com IF/ELSE no RV. Que comédia. Vou dar a resposta como certa agora.

Comment: @Mr_Anderson, quer explicar porque a resposta está certa? O seu problema era a `url.imgview` ser nula ou era o uso de `holder.getAdapterPosition()`? Pergunto pois ainda não consegui perceber qual era o seu problema.

Comment: Olhando aqui agora, depois que eu arrumei o problema do IF sem ELSE o problema parou; então, creio que o problema era só no IF/ELSE.

Comment: @Mr_Anderson Que bom que resolveu, esse "problema" do if/else é conhecido, por isso coloquei aquele exemplo, mas é sempre bom que quando vc tenha algum problema, poste o seu código junto, abraços.

Comment: @ramaral a pergunta estava mal feita, mas como o Leonardo tem experiência usando RecyclerView ele conseguiu, corretamente, supor que o usuário que perguntou estava cometendo um dos erros mais comuns no uso da RecyclerView. Acho que dar -1 na resposta dele foi algo muito esquisito (não estou falando que foi você). Deveria ser dado -1 na pergunta! E comentado na mesma para que fosse melhorada a qualidade. Por sinal, a qualidade das perguntas no Stack em Português é sofrível, parece que só tem gente querendo resolver dever de faculdade/curso aqui! E eu tb usando os comentários como chat! :-(

Comment: @Loudenvier Eu também tenho experiência em *RecyclerView*, daí saber que as causas daquele problema poderem ser muitas. O Leonardo teve sorte em acertar. Eu, quando não tenho a certeza não respondo. É claro que o Leonardo tem todo o direito de responder às perguntas que quiser e como quiser, não tem é o direito de dizer que é *"guerra de reputação"* quando é negativada um resposta dele. Eu dei -1 na pergunta e na resposta, também votei para fechar a pergunta como "não clara". Responder a este tipo de perguntas é um incentivo à existência de más perguntas.

Comment: @ramaral você nem chegou a fazer um comentário na pergunta pedindo mais informações. Não acho que foi muita sorte do Leonardo também não, quando li a pergunta, de cara, imaginei que fosse isso, e já ia pedir mais informações, mas vi que já havia uma resposta e deixei para lá. Nossas posturas são diferentes nesses casos, o que é bom, pois, como já dizia o poeta, toda unanimidade é burra. Abraçso.

Comment: @Loudenvier Que mais informações deveria pedir? Se fosse um usuário novo tinha pedido o código, mas não é o caso.

Comment: @ramaral como disse, diferença de posturas.